# Words with swedish letters don't show in \hl{}

Tags: color, highlighting, letters, soul

I want to highlight a Swedish word with  `\hl{en kassör}`, but the word `kassör` just disappears and only `en` is highlighted.

I use the pdfLaTex compiler in v2 Overleaf.
I use the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{color, soul}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item bla bla bla:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \hl{(1) en kassör}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`soul` is only for ascii fonts. for extension with non ascii characters as are in Swedish and many other languages, is intended the package `soulutf8`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{color, soulutf8}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item bla bla bla:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \hl{(1) en kassör}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]